# EditText Android| input text by pressing a button

Tags: android, mobile, android-edittext

How to implement the method, when the button is clicked, EditText can be edited. Before this, EditText must be closed for text entry. 
code located below does not help

```
 Entertext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Total.setFocusable(true);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this use **`android:focusable="false"`** in xml to disable your `EditText`

```
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false" />
```

now    enabled your `Edittext` inside button click listener using `android:focusable` like this

```
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            edittext.setFocusable(true);
            edittext.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            edittext.setEnabled(true);
            edittext.requestFocus();
        }
    });
```

Comment: This method is suitable, but the text before the plot shows a light gray. How can I fix this?

Comment: What is "ans"??

Comment: @ДанилФилиппов try my updated answer i have made some changes

Comment: And how to change the method so that when you click the button again, my EditText was closed for editing

Comment: @ДанилФилиппов like this **`edittext.setFocusable(false);`**

Answer (score 0):

make edittext in xml as focusable false like below ..

```
        android:focusable="false"
```

then after click event used below code..

```
        Entertext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Total.setFocusable(true);
            Total.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            Total.requestFocus();

        }
    });
```

you can also used enable and disable concept in edittext.